# Can the DllMain of an .exe be called?

Tags: winapi, dll, exe

My question is not exactly the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186502/dllmain-in-an-exe) (it's not theoretical, there is only a main thread without message loop, InitInstance and ExitInstance are no fitting calls).

I'm using a console app without message loop; this app loads an exe with the LoadLibrary function, so that it can use its exported functions. Bad news: the DllMain function of the exe is not called (and I verified the symbols tables, using a def file, DllMain appears correctly); [the doc says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583.aspx) it's called if the loaded module is a DLL (too bad).

What are the conditions (if they exist) which could lead to the execution of the exe's DllMain function when LoadLibrary is called (and maybe again when FreeLibrary is called)?

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious condition is that the process calling LoadLibrary() explicitly gets GetProcAddress("DllMain") and then calls it.

Comment: Normally, `GetProcAddress("DllMain")` will return `NULL`.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: Source? You may be looking at a C++ DLL where the runtime has wrapped `DllMain` in its own entry point with a different name.

Comment: Using `GetProcAddress`, you can only get the addresses of functions being specified in the [exports table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll?view=msvc-170) of a DLL (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/getprocaddress?view=msvc-170)). While `gcc` puts all functions in the exports table by default (you can change this), Microsoft's compiler requires you to [specify manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/export-exports-a-function?view=msvc-170) which functions are in the exports table.

Comment: Because normally the `DllMain` function should only be called by Windows internally, no programmer specifies that this function shall be placed in the exports table - so it cannot be accessed by `GetProcAddress`. I just tested on my computer (Windows 10): Of 66 DLLs in `\windows\system32`, only 2 returned `non-NULL` for `GetProcAddress("DllMain")`.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: I think you're missing a bit of context here. The question is about an **executable** with a `DllMain`, loaded as if it's a library. That's not a normal setup. Also, `DllMain` is optional, and entirely pointless for resource-only DLL's. It would be a performance hit to get `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` notifications in DLL's that don't care about them.

Comment: Ah. I see. However, even in this case the OP must make sure that the `DllMain` function is exported. If it is simply a "normal" function in his EXE file, it is even possible that the Linker removes the function from the EXE file when optimizing...

Comment: @MartinRosenau: That's why the question states that the `.def` file (defining the exports) includes `DllMain`.

Answer (score 3):

The conditions are:

1) Binary being loaded was compiled as DLL (when using gcc/ld it means using `--shared` option; If you use `--shared`, resulting file will be a dll, and will not run, see below)

2) `IMAGE_FILE_DLL` is set in PE file header of the binary file being loaded. If it is set, file is a dll, and Windows linker will call its `DllMain()` function for you when it links this file to your program (doesn't matter how it's linked - `LoadLibrary()` at runtime or `-llibraryname` at compile time). For that the file must also satisfy (1). But with this flag the binary file being loaded will not be runnable. If `IMAGE_FILE_DLL` is not set, `DllMain()` will not be called when file is loaded into your program.

Compiling dll with `--shared` and then manually removing `IMAGE_FILE_DLL` from its header (i.e. by using hex editor) will not work - when you run it, only `DllMain()` will be executed, and `fdwReason` will be a non-defined number (`0x28ffd4` on my machine).

**Update**

All DLL and EXE files on Windows are PE files, the difference is how they are linked, and which flags are set in their headers. That is why i write `file being loaded`, not `dll being loaded`.

The last paragraph also describes the scenario where you compile the file as dll, and then turn it into exe by messing with its header. It doesn't work.

Naming has nothing to do with it (you can choose any name, and with some `pexports`+`dlltool` tinkering you can create an import library for an .exe file and be able to link it as `-lexenamewithoutextension`

To clarify:

- if you compile it without `--shared`:

  - `IMAGE_FILE_DLL` will not be set in it, it will be runnable, but DllMain() will NOT be called when you link it.
- if you compile it with `--shared`:

  - `IMAGE_FILE_DLL` will be set in it, it will NOT be runnable, but DllMain() will be called when you link it.
- if you compile it without `--shared`, then switch on the `IMAGE_FILE_DLL` flag in it manually:

  - it will NOT be runnable anymore, and no DllMain() will be called when you link it.
- if you compile it with `--shared`, then switch off the `IMAGE_FILE_DLL` flag in it manually:

  - it will be runnable, but DllMain() will be executed instead of main(), and DllMain() will NOT be called when you link it.

Comment: The question specifically mentions loading an executable (`.exe`) using `LoadLibrary`, and not a DLL. Please re-read the question.

Comment: Your edit changes nothing. Nowhere does the question say that the file was compiled/linked as anything but a `.exe` file. (Executable files on Windows can export functions just like a DLL without having any need to compile it as a DLL first.)

Comment: The question was: "What are the conditions (if they exist) which could lead to the execution of the exe's DllMain function when LoadLibrary is called (and maybe again when FreeLibrary is called)?"
That is what i'm answering. To have DllMain() called automatically you have to compile the binary as a shared library and have the DLL flag set in it.

Comment: You still missed my point. :-) If you have an *.EXE*, there's no *DLLMain* to be automatically called. Sure you can have a function named `DLLMain`, but that's just like naming a class `Car` and expecting to be able to use it to get to your doctor's appt. There is no `auto-callable DLLMain()` function in an .EXE, so there's no way you can get it auto-called when you load the .EXE with `LoadLibrary()`.

Comment: You say he missed your point, but then you proceed to make a statement which is mostly covered by his answer. The answer from LRN appears to be a superset of most of your statement. The part he did not have was the _why_ it works out that way, though Martin brings that up in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Completing the good answer of [MSalters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15416/msalters):

So, then, call the "fake" DllMain with DLL_XXX_ATTACH just after LoadLibrary and with DLL_XXX_DETACH just before FreeLibrary, and make manually the other calls.

<s>Another following implementation would be to build and load an interface DLL which could callback automatically the EXE on its fake DllMain (I don't know if it could work); but it may be more complicated than just manually calling the fake DllMain in a number of cases.</s> (can't LoadLibrary in a DllMain)

Comment: You can't call LoadLibrary("your.exe") from the DllMain in your helper DLL - part of the long list of things you can't do there. That makes your helper DLL rather tricky to use; it can't be a simple wrapper/forwarder,